# SQL Server stored procedure - delete rows based on multiple parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need help figuring out how to build a stored procedure that will delete rows based on two parameters.

Assume I have two identical tables, `Table1` and `Table2` both containing columns `Date`, `Name`, and `Number`. I want to delete rows from `Table1` based on `Date` and `Name`, and `Insert Into Table1` `From Table2`.

Essentially I want it to function somewhere along the lines of:

```
Delete From Table1
Where (Table1.Date = Table2.Date) AND (Table1.Name = Table2.Name)
```

and then:

```
Insert Into Table1
Select * From Table2
```

I'm not familiar with how stored procedures work so I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: This is really just a T-SQL question and doesn't really have anything specific to do with a stored procedure. Just do a delete on join and then do your insert statement.

Comment: You really should try looking at the documentation for the product you are working with. Here is how you create a procedure. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query for creating this kind of procedure goes like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DummyProc 
    @Date DATE, 
    @Name VARCHAR(20) --Or NVARCHAR if you have UNICODE data
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Table_1
    WHERE Table_1.Date = @Date AND Table_1.Name= @Name

    INSERT INTO Table_1
    SELECT Date, Name, Number --You can specify columns
    FROM Table_2
END
GO
```

And for executing with query:

```
EXEC dbo.DummyProc 'enter Date here', 'enter Name here';
GO
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you for your help!